# Get top n rows without order by operator in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I had a table

```sql
CREATE TABLE StatsFull (
  Timestamp Int32,
  Uid String,
  ErrorCode Int32,
  Name String,
  Version String,
  Date Date MATERIALIZED toDate(Timestamp),
  Time DateTime MATERIALIZED toDateTime(Timestamp)
) ENGINE = MergeTree() PARTITION BY toMonday(Date)
ORDER BY Time SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

And I needed to get top 100 Names with unique Uids or top 100 ErrorCodes.
The obvious query is

```sql
SELECT Name, uniq(PcId) as cnt FROM StatsFull
WHERE Time > subtractDays(toDate(now()), 1)
GROUP BY Name ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 100
```

But data was too big so I created an AggregatingMergeTree because I did not need data filtering by hour (just by date).

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW StatsAggregated (
  Date Date,
  ProductName String,
  ErrorCode Int32,
  Name String,
  Version String,
  UniqUsers AggregateFunction(uniq, String),
) ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree() PARTITION BY toMonday(Date)
ORDER BY
  (
    Date,
    ProductName,
    ErrorCode,
    Name,
    Version
  ) SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192 AS
SELECT
  Date,
  ProductName,
  ErrorCode,
  Name,
  Version,
  uniqState(Uid) AS UniqUsers,
FROM
  StatsFull
GROUP BY
  Date,
  ProductName,
  ErrorCode,
  Name,
  Version
```

And my current query is:

```sql
SELECT Name FROM StatsAggregated 
WHERE Date > subtractDays(toDate(now()), 1)
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY uniqMerge(UniqUsers) DESC LIMIT 100
```

The query was working fine, however eventually data rows in a day became more and now it too greedy by memory. So I am looking for some optimization.

I have found the function **topK(N)(column)** that returns an array of the most frequent values in the specified column but it isn't what I need.

Comment: your example is pretty abstract - could you provide the real example and schema definition? You need to consider the assignment the right *primary keys*, *partitioning* etc in MergeTree or rely on the abilities of AggregatingMergeTree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to the next points:

- where possible prefer use [SimpleAggregateFunction](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/836ac810a7a5696449aa70b4a120c0c0f00e1582/dbms/tests/queries/0_stateless/00915_simple_aggregate_function.sql) instead of [AggregateFunction](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/data_types/nested_data_structures/aggregatefunction/)
- use [uniqCombined](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/agg_functions/reference/#agg_function-uniqcombined)/uniqCombined64 that "consumes several times less memory" in compare with [uniq](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/agg_functions/reference/#agg_function-uniq)
- reduce the count of dimensions in aggregated-view (it looks like *ProductName* and *Version* can be omitted)

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW StatsAggregated (
  Date Date,
  Name String,
  ErrorCode Int32
  UniqUsers AggregateFunction(uniq, String),
) ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree()
PARTITION BY toMonday(Date)
ORDER BY (Date, Name, ErrorCode) AS
SELECT Date, Name, ErrorCode, uniqState(Uid) AS UniqUsers,
FROM StatsFull
GROUP BY Date, Name, ErrorCode;
```

- adding extra 'heuristic' constraints to *when*-clause of resulting query

```sql
SELECT Name, uniqMerge(UniqUsers) uniqUsers 
FROM StatsAggregated 
WHERE Date > subtractDays(toDate(now()), 1)
  AND uniqUsers > 12345 /* <-- 12345 is 'heuristic' number that you evaluate based on your data */
  AND ErrorCode = 0 /* apply any other conditions to narrow the result set as short as possible */
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY uniqUsers DESC LIMIT 100
```

- use [sampling](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/select/#select-sample-clause)

```sql
/* Raw-table */

CREATE TABLE StatsFull (
 /* .. */
) ENGINE = MergeTree() 
PARTITION BY toMonday(Date)
SAMPLE BY xxHash32(Uid) /* < -- */
ORDER BY Time, xxHash32(Uid)

/* Applying sampling to raw-table can make faster the short-term queries (period in several hours etc) */

SELECT Name, uniq(PcId) as cnt 
FROM StatsFull
SAMPLE 0.05 /* <-- */
WHERE Time > subtractHours(now(), 6) /* <-- hours-period */
GROUP BY Name 
ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 100


/* Aggregated-table */

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW StatsAggregated (
  Date Date,
  ProductName String,
  ErrorCode Int32,
  Name String,
  Version String,
  UniqUsers AggregateFunction(uniq, String),
) ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree() 
PARTITION BY toMonday(Date)
SAMPLE BY intHash32(toInt32(Date)) /* < -- not sure that is good to choose */
ORDER BY (intHash32(toInt32(Date)), ProductName, ErrorCode, Name, Version)
SELECT /* .. */ FROM StatsFull GROUP BY /* .. */**

/* Applying sampling to aggregated-table can make faster the long-term queries (period in several weeks, months etc) */

SELECT Name 
FROM StatsAggregated 
SAMPLE 0.1 /* < -- */
WHERE Date > subtractMonths(toDate(now()), 3) /* <-- months-period */
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY uniqMerge(UniqUsers) DESC LIMIT 100
```

- use [distributed query processing](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/distributed/). Splitting data into several parts (shards) allows making distributed processing; additional increase of processing performance gives using [distributed_group_by_no_merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57838159/303298)-query setting.

Comment: I will try your suggestions. Cannot reduce count of columns in aggregated view because filtering by ProductName and Version needed. It looks like Sampling is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

if you need transpone array to rows you could use arrayJoin

```
SELECT Name, arrayJoin(topK(100)(Count)) AS top100_Count FROM Stats
```