# what is the effect of distributed_group_by_no_merge

Tags: clickhouse

I know that the distributed node does not combine intermediate results from shards by using [distributed_group_by_no_merge](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/332).

The following SQL

```sql
select sum(xxxxx),xxxxx from (
    select sum(xxxx),xxxx 
    from (
        select count(xxx),xxx 
        from distributed_table group by xxx )  
    group by xxxx SETTINGS distributed_group_by_no_merge = 1
) group by xxxxx
```

I want to know that which part of sql will be sent to MergeTree node to execute by using distributed_group_by_no_merge？ is it？***select count(xxx),xxx from distributed_table group by xxx )  group by xxxx SETTINGS distributed_group_by_no_merge = 1***

how does the parameter of distributed_group_by_no_merge  change the behavior of  distributed query？which part of sql execute on MergeTree node and which part of sql execute on distributed node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[distributed_group_by_no_merge](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings#distributed-group-by-no-merge)-param affects the way how the initiator-node (it is a node which runs distributed query) will form the final result of a distributed query:

- either by merging [aggregated intermediate states](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/aggregatefunction/) coming from shards by itself (it required copying full aggregated intermediate states from shards to initiator-node) [distributed_group_by_no_merge = 0 (default mode)]
- or get already final result from shards (when each shard merges an intermediate aggregation state on its side and send to initiator-node only the final result). It provides a significant improvement in performance and resource consumption but requires the right selection of the sharding key [distributed_group_by_no_merge = 1]

---

I would put *distributed_group_by_no_merge* at the same level of subquery where defined distributed table to explicitly define your intention and avoid confusion when there are several distributed-subqueries.

---

Let's look at the way how to check the differences between the two modes (will use [_shard_num](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/special/distributed/#virtual-columns)-virtual column):

1. distributed_group_by_no_merge=0

```sql
SELECT
    groupUniqArray(_shard_num) AS shards,
    ..
FROM table
WHERE ..
GROUP BY ..
SETTINGS distributed_group_by_no_merge = 0

/* Aggregated states were merged into ONE result set on initiator-node.
┌─shards────┬─ ..
│ [2, 1, 3] │  ..
└───────────┴─ ..
*/
```

2. distributed_group_by_no_merge=1

```sql
SELECT
    groupUniqArray(_shard_num) AS shards,
    ..
FROM table
WHERE ..
GROUP BY ..
SETTINGS distributed_group_by_no_merge = 1

/* Get a set of final results (not aggregated states) from each shard. They should be unioned manually.
┌─shards─┬─ ..
│ [2]    │  ..
│ [1]    │  ..
│ [3]    │  ..
└────────┴─ ..
*/
```

---

[How to avoid merging high cardinality sub-select aggregations on distributed tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57825939/303298)

Comment: 1.when not using distributed_group_by_no_merge,  
  subquery only internal part of a query from distributed_table will be executed on shads,  
  all other parts outside ( ) will be executed at an initiator node.  
  [why not array join execute on mergetree node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61743180/what-is-the-effect-of-distributed-group-by-no-merge)  
2.when using distributed_group_by_no_merge=1 at the same level of subquery,  
  the-same-level subquery will be executed on shards,  
  and the outside aggregate query will be executed on distributed node.  
right?

Comment: 1) I updated my answer, please look at it. 2) yes, 'outside aggregates' will be run on initial-node independently from value of *distributed_group_by_no_merge*-param. The key difference is where be calculated the final result of distributed query - on initiator-node or each shard separately (understanding the *intermediate aggregation state* and *merging of intermediate aggregation states* help to clarify this topic).