# How to setup ClickHouse to efficiently fetch users that were last time active at a particular day

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I need to list all users that stopped their activity at some day in the past.
As the input data for clickhouse I have a stream of logs of users activity (just timestamps and user ids basically). As a naive approach I'd simply write the activity logs in ClickHouse and then just query them with:

```
SELECT userId, maxDayDate
FROM (SELECT userId, MAX(dayDate) AS maxDayDate
      FROM user_activity_logs_distributed
      GROUP BY userId)
WHERE maxDayDate = '2020-05-16'
```

but this query ends up with a full table scan, takes too much of resources. I've tried to use AggregatingMergeTree, aggregating the max day date on fly, but this solution again leads to full scans since it's impossible to use AggregateFunction fields in WHERE, to narrow down the records scope.

The schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE user_activity_logs (
    userId          UInt32,
    dayDate         DateTime
)
ENGINE = ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree('...', '...')
ORDER BY (
    dayDate,
    userId
)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;



CREATE TABLE user_activity_logs_distributed (
    userId          UInt32,
    dayDate         DateTime
) ENGINE = Distributed(cluster_cross_r1, default, user_activity_logs);
```

Comment: could you provide the schema of table *user_activity_logs_distributed*?

Comment: @vladimir updated

Comment: your select query is good enough. You can create another table using materialized view and materialize there ( userId, MAX(dayDate) )  if you need to improve this particular query. And can remove sub-query  and place maxDayDate = '2020-05-16' into having section.

Comment: @DenisZhuravlev I'm not an expert, but isn't HAVING just filters out the already grouped data? The grouped data itself must be calculated first - this is the bottleneck because in order to be grouped in my case, the table needs to be full-scanned and loaded into memory.

Comment: @kas-kad having works a bit earlier than where in the outer query

Answer (score 0):

I see these ways:

1. Modify the origin query

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT userId
FROM user_activity_logs_distributed
WHERE (dayDate = '2020-05-16') AND (userId NOT IN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT userId
    FROM user_activity_logs_distributed
    WHERE dayDate > '2020-05-16'
))
```

2. Use [data skipping index](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree/#table_engine-mergetree-data_skipping-indexes)

[minmax](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree/#available-types-of-indices) is fit for your case.

3. Use [AggregatingMergeTree](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/aggregatingmergetree/) to precalculate required aggregate(s)

```sql
/* this is not replicated example */

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW user_activity_logs_mv
(
  userId Int32,
  max_date SimpleAggregateFunction(max, Date)
) ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree()
ORDER BY (userId)
AS 
SELECT
  userId,
  maxState(dayDate)
FROM user_activity_logs
GROUP BY userId


SELECT userId, max(max_date)
FROM user_activity_logs_mv
WHERE userId = 1
GROUP BY userId
```

---

If sharding key based on *userId* then can be useful use [distributed_group_by_no_merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61743180/what-is-the-effect-of-distributed-group-by-no-merge) for origin query.